# Google Calendar Domain wide acess 401 for calendar

Tags: spring-boot, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I have a service account which has the domain level delegation present for GSuite.

I want to read Calander of all users in the domain to schedule some tasks on some logic

I've Fallowed this

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "";
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;
    final DateTime date1 = new DateTime("2017-05-05T16:30:00.000+05:30");
    final DateTime date2 = new DateTime(new Date());


@Bean
    public GoogleCredential googleCredential() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        try {
            httpTransport= GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId("xxx"
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("xxx.p12"))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"))
                    .setServiceAccountUser("xxx")
                    .build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw  e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw  e;
        }
    }
```

In My Test Class

```
@Autowired
    GoogleCredential googleCredential;

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "";
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;
    final DateTime date1 = new DateTime("2017-05-05T16:30:00.000+05:30");
    final DateTime date2 = new DateTime(new Date());

    @PostConstruct
    public void TestCalender(){
        try {

            httpTransport= GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events eventList;
            String message;
            client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, googleCredential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            Calendar.Events events = client.events();

            eventList = events.list("primary").setTimeMin(date1).setTimeMax(date2).execute();

            message = eventList.getItems().toString();
            System.out.println("My:" + eventList.getItems());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting below exception

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:897)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.api.service.GoogleTest.TestCalender(GoogleTest.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.api.GoogleCalApplication.main(GoogleCalApplication.java:31)
```

when I change "primary" to actual user email
it gives

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1097)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.api.service.GoogleTest.TestCalender(GoogleTest.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.api.GoogleCalApplication.main(GoogleCalApplication.java:35)
```

Comment: try changing "primary" to the email address of the user you are trying to access.   setServiceAccountUser("xxx") is also the email of the user you are trying to impersonate?

Comment: when I change "primay" to user emailAddress it gives com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}

Comment: Try removing .setServiceAccountUser("xxx") just to check there isnt an issue with your service account authentication.  You should be able to access the service accounts calendar account.   (put it back to primary)

Comment: By making "primary" it gets empty array. It doesnt fail. Also this is service account. It wont have any calendar events untill shared

Comment: Welcome to service accounts.  They are dummy users they have their own Google calendar account which can be inserted into and read from.  By returning an empty array it works because you havent added anything. So you know know this is not an issue with your code.  Its an issue with the setup of the delegation, or your use of the delegation. Contact the gsuite admin have them check that you have been granted access.

Comment: I've shared a normal user calendar to this Service User & then it showed events of that user. My question is why to have to share a calendar. When this service account has full access

Comment: Thats what  .setServiceAccountUser("xxx")  it lets you delegate to the user you want to access.   If it had full access for the user you are adding there then it would be working.  Delegation doesnt give you access to all of the users calendar accounts It gives you access to pretend that you are all of those users and access their calendar accounts.   There is a difference.